# Correct way of saying "SELECT count(dinstinct d.domain) WHERE r.rdns LIKE '%' | r.rdns"?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables: let's call them `d` and `r`. I'd like to find the number of `d.domain` that are a valid left-anchored substring of `dns` field in table `r`. I have no indexes and `r` has 1 billion rows and while `d` has 90 million ones. How do I write the query?

The PostgreSQL version is 9.3.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT d.domain)
FROM d
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM r
  WHERE r.domain LIKE '%' || d.domain
);
```

EXISTS will have the potential of being faster than a JOIN, since it'd be a semi-join.

I'd create a b-tree index on d.domain and see if a loose index scan on that would help fetching distinct domains faster than DISTINCT. See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan

Also see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Reverse_string for potentially speeding up the suffix pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    dd.domain,
    COUNT(r.dns)
FROM d AS dd
JOIN r AS rr
ON rr.dns LIKE '%' + dd.domain
GROUP BY dd.domain
```